# Always doesn't fire if there is just one fail

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

my code works fine as long as every request returns successful. But if there ist just one single fail "always" doesn't fire.

I expect "always" always to fire. So far I had no luck finding an answer to my problem. "complete" (which I use for single requests) doesn't work. "then" neither.

```
var counter = { ok:0, fail:0 };

for(var i in toDoList)
{
  spRequest[i] = $.ajax({...})
  .done( function() { counter.ok   ++; } )
  .fail( function() { counter.fail ++; } );
}

$.when.apply(this, spRequest)
.always
(
  function()
  {
    if ( spResp.ok == paybackTable.length )
    {
      console.log( "everything went just fine" );
    }
    else
    {
      console.log( "there were some problems:" );
      console.log( "- Requests OK: " + counter.ok );
      console.log( "- Requests failed: " + counter.fail );
    }
  }
);
```

my "There were some problems" section is never reached

Comment: This might help:
Handle well error in ajax, and your code will be able to do the $.when.apply line. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810128/try-catch-with-jquery-ajax-request
Use window.onerror to see errors

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there are some inaccuracies in your code. First of all, when you call `$.when.apply()`, between `.when()` parenthesis, you have to put "`$`" as first arguments, then your array `spRequest`. If you work with `jQuery.Deferred` you can control better the final result of your Deferreds (ajax calls and so on...).
So, you push in `spRequest` array your Deferreds, that are executed ASAP. `$.when.apply($,spRequest)` waits for all Deferreds to be resolved or rejected.
I deliberately put `self.resolve()` in every `ajax.fail()` instead of `self.reject()` because of two reasons:

- you want to count your ajax fails;
- if in a series of Deferred objects one of them fails, `$.when.fail()` fires and I think is not what you're searching for, or, better, I suppose that the files called by your ajax calls exist and can be correctly called. On the other hand, if it is not so, you have two possibilities:

  - use `self.reject()` on `ajax.fail()`;
  - consider to check statusCode in your ajax call:

  `$.ajax({
    statusCode: {
      404: function() {
       //resolve and counter ++ stuffs in here
      }
    }
  });`

Here it is an example that goals your needs:

*** index.php ***

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST DEFERRED</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>TEST DEFERRED</h1>
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*** test.js ***

```
var counter = { ok:0, fail:0 }
,toDoList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
,spRequest = [];

for(var i in toDoList)
{
  console.log(i, i&1);
  if(i&1)
  {
    console.log('odd, request an ok ajax call');
    spRequest[i] = jQuery.Deferred(function(){
      console.log('function ok called!');
      var self = this;

      $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/ajax_return_ok.php',
        async: true,
        data : {},
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json'
      }).done( function(d) {
        console.log(d);
        if(d.is_error)
        {
          counter.fail ++;
          self.resolve();
        } else {
          counter.ok   ++;
          self.resolve();
        }

      }).fail( function(j) {
        console.log(j.responseText);
        //# fail of ajax call
        counter.fail ++;
        self.resolve();
      });

    });
  } else {
    console.log('odd, request an error ajax call');
    spRequest[i] = jQuery.Deferred(function(){
      console.log('function error called!');
      var self = this;

      $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/ajax_return_error.php',
        async: true,
        data : {},
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json'
      }).done( function(d) {
        console.log(d);
        if(d.is_error)
        {
          counter.fail ++;
          self.resolve();
        } else {
          counter.ok   ++;
          self.resolve();
        }

      }).fail( function(j) {
        console.log(j.responseText);
        //# fail of ajax call
        counter.fail ++;
        self.resolve();
      });

    });
  }

}


jQuery.when.apply($,spRequest).done(function(){
  console.log('when done');
}).fail(function(){
  console.log('when fail');
}).always(function(){
  if ( counter.fail === 0 )
  {
    console.log( "everything went just fine" );
  }
  else
  {
    console.log( "there were some problems:" );
    console.log( "- Requests OK: " + counter.ok );
    console.log( "- Requests failed: " + counter.fail );
  }
});
```

*** ajax_return_error.php ***

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array('is_error' => true,'error_message' => 'this is an error message'));
```

*** ajax_return_ok.php ***

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array('is_error' => false,'result' => 'ok'));
```

Apologize in advance for not having create a Fiddle.

Hope my answer helps.